# ContentProvider : How to map multiple codes to the same UriMatcher wildcard

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I am currently stuck in a situation where I need to delete rows from the same table but using different column names. For the sake of discussion, let's consider the following table :

`Table Name : Sample`

`Columns : sample_1_string,sample_2_string.`

I want to implement two delete functions. One that can delete items from this table using values in `sample_1_string` column and the second one that can delete items from this table using values in `sample_2_string` column.

When working with a `ContentProvider`, one generally maps a path with a particular code which can later be used to decide what operation to execute on the database. In the above example, I could provide a `UriMatcher` for sample_1_string columns

```
matcher.addURI(authority, DatabaseContract.PATH_SAMPLETABLE + "/*", 1);
```

However, the above uri matcher will end up catching all uri that have some text followed after the directory name. How can my `ContentProvider` implementation distinguish between requests that are asking to delete based on `sample_1_string` column and those that are asking to delete based on `sample_2_string` column.

Comment: Why don't you just use two different paths to distinguish, instead of just the table name for both? For example, `PATH_SAMPLE_1` and `PATH_SAMPLE_2`. You don't have to use the table name at all in your URIs, and in fact they can be any valid URI you want, but you could certainly append those different paths to your existing `PATH_SAMPLETABLE`.

Comment: @MikeM. I was trying to follow a "standard" mechanism such that all Uri matchers always contain the table name and the path that follows after that will always be considered as the column name in case of update or delete requests. I guess this won't be possible so I have gone ahead with your suggestion of defining Uris for separate columns. Thanks,